# How to calculate PSD in particular frequency bands with spetrogram() in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I can do STFT with the `spectrogram()` in Matlab:

```
[S,F,T,P]=spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,nfft,fs)
```

For example, sample rate of signal `X` is 128Hz. The STFT is executed with 2s-long window(256 points) with 50% overlapping. Then `S` has 129 rows.

What does each row means? And how to calculate PSD in particular bands, such as [40,50]Hz?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Each row is a frequency. The output argument `F` is a vector of frequencies at which the spectrogram is computed. Based on `F`,  you can pick the rows you need from `S` or `P`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you!